# Exception error: Inconsistent sequencing: if used on one of the class's members

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

This exception is being thrown when my console application tries to deserialize the XML.

> Inconsistent sequencing: if used on one of the class's members, the
>   'Order' property is required on all particle-like members, please
>   explicitly set 'Order' using XmlElement, XmlAnyElement or XmlArray
>   custom attribute on class member 'worksheetReference'.

The XML I am trying to deserialize looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<worksheetReport xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReport">
  <worksheetRefence>
    <worksheetReference xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetIdentityType">306</worksheetReference>
  </worksheetRefence>
  <WorksheetReportRows>
    <worksheetReportRow>
      <worksheetRefence xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">
        <worksheetReference xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetIdentityType">306</worksheetReference>
      </worksheetRefence>
      <invoiceNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">INTEBKKEN00000005672</invoiceNumber>
      <orderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">65406504</orderNumber>
      <incoTerm xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">CIF</incoTerm>
      <incoTermLocation xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">HEATHROW</incoTermLocation>
      <lineNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">1</lineNumber>
      <lineOrderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">111</lineOrderNumber>
      <productCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">PROD01</productCode>
      <sku xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">SKU01</sku>
      <quantity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">1.000</quantity>
      <unitPrice xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">94.99</unitPrice>
      <itemNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">0</itemNumber>
      <commodityCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">8302100090</commodityCode>
      <originCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">TH</originCountry>
      <goodsDescription xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GOATS CHEESE</goodsDescription>
      <consignorName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">JONATHAN CHAPMAN</consignorName>
      <consignorStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">1406 CARALEA VALLEY DR</consignorStreet>
      <consignorCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">CONCORD</consignorCity>
      <consignorPostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">28027</consignorPostCode>
      <consignorCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">US</consignorCountry>
      <consigneeEori xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GBPR</consigneeEori>
      <consigneeName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">ALBERTO MARTINEZ GLEZ</consigneeName>
      <consigneeStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">PLAZA SAN LORENZO NO2  1O DERECHA</consigneeStreet>
      <consigneeCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">LEON</consigneeCity>
      <consigneePostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">24007</consigneePostCode>
      <consigneeCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">ES</consigneeCountry>
      <aiStatementCode1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">BULKD</aiStatementCode1>
      <aiStatementText1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GEO/251LVBI/0916</aiStatementText1>
      <aiStatementCode2 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">LIC99</aiStatementCode2>
    </worksheetReportRow>
    <worksheetReportRow>
      <worksheetRefence xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">
        <worksheetReference xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetIdentityType">306</worksheetReference>
      </worksheetRefence>
      <invoiceNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">INTEBKKEN00000005672</invoiceNumber>
      <orderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">65406504</orderNumber>
      <incoTerm xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">CIF</incoTerm>
      <incoTermLocation xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">HEATHROW</incoTermLocation>
      <lineNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">2</lineNumber>
      <lineOrderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">222</lineOrderNumber>
      <productCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">PROD02</productCode>
      <sku xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">SKU02</sku>
      <quantity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">5.000</quantity>
      <unitPrice xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">139.99</unitPrice>
      <itemNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">0</itemNumber>
      <commodityCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">4901910000</commodityCode>
      <originCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">TH</originCountry>
      <goodsDescription xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">A STICK OF ROCK</goodsDescription>
      <consignorName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">ADAM DANGOOR</consignorName>
      <consignorStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">35340 ROAD 603</consignorStreet>
      <consignorCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">MADERA</consignorCity>
      <consignorPostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">93638819</consignorPostCode>
      <consignorCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">US</consignorCountry>
      <consigneeEori xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GBPR</consigneeEori>
      <consigneeName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">ALESSANDRO CAMPO</consigneeName>
      <consigneeStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">VIALE EVARISTO STEFINI 8 GF FOTOGRA</consigneeStreet>
      <consigneeCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">MILANO</consigneeCity>
      <consigneePostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">20125</consigneePostCode>
      <consigneeCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">IT</consigneeCountry>
      <aiStatementCode1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">BULKD</aiStatementCode1>
      <aiStatementText1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GEO/251LVBI/0916</aiStatementText1>
      <aiStatementCode2 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">LIC99</aiStatementCode2>
    </worksheetReportRow>
    <worksheetReportRow>
      <worksheetRefence xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">
        <worksheetReference xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetIdentityType">306</worksheetReference>
      </worksheetRefence>
      <invoiceNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">INTEBKKEN00000005672</invoiceNumber>
      <orderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">65406504</orderNumber>
      <incoTerm xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">CIF</incoTerm>
      <incoTermLocation xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">HEATHROW</incoTermLocation>
      <lineNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">3</lineNumber>
      <lineOrderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">333</lineOrderNumber>
      <productCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">PROD03</productCode>
      <sku xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">SKU03</sku>
      <quantity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">1.000</quantity>
      <unitPrice xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">29.99</unitPrice>
      <itemNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">0</itemNumber>
      <commodityCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">4901910000</commodityCode>
      <originCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">TH</originCountry>
      <goodsDescription xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">A 9 IRON</goodsDescription>
      <consignorName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">HIU YU</consignorName>
      <consignorStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">17814 BAINTREE ST</consignorStreet>
      <consignorCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">ROWLAND HEIGHTS</consignorCity>
      <consignorPostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">91748420</consignorPostCode>
      <consignorCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">US</consignorCountry>
      <consigneeEori xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GBPR</consigneeEori>
      <consigneeName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">ALLARD</consigneeName>
      <consigneeStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">RUE DES PALAIS N55</consigneeStreet>
      <consigneeCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">BRUSSELS</consigneeCity>
      <consigneePostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">1030</consigneePostCode>
      <consigneeCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">BE</consigneeCountry>
      <aiStatementCode1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">BULKD</aiStatementCode1>
      <aiStatementText1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GEO/251LVBI/0916</aiStatementText1>
      <aiStatementCode2 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">LIC99</aiStatementCode2>
    </worksheetReportRow>
    <worksheetReportRow>
      <worksheetRefence xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">
        <worksheetReference xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetIdentityType">306</worksheetReference>
      </worksheetRefence>
      <invoiceNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">INTEBKKEN00000005672</invoiceNumber>
      <orderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">65406504</orderNumber>
      <incoTerm xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">CIF</incoTerm>
      <incoTermLocation xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">HEATHROW</incoTermLocation>
      <lineNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">4</lineNumber>
      <lineOrderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">444</lineOrderNumber>
      <productCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">PROD04</productCode>
      <sku xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">SKU04</sku>
      <quantity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">1.000</quantity>
      <unitPrice xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">59.99</unitPrice>
      <itemNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">0</itemNumber>
      <commodityCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">8302100090</commodityCode>
      <originCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">TH</originCountry>
      <goodsDescription xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">A HAT WITH MICKEY MOUSE EARS</goodsDescription>
      <consignorName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">JUAN MAYMI</consignorName>
      <consignorStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">6724 PERIMETER LOOP RD</consignorStreet>
      <consignorCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">DUBLIN</consignorCity>
      <consignorPostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">43017320</consignorPostCode>
      <consignorCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">US</consignorCountry>
      <consigneeEori xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GBPR</consigneeEori>
      <consigneeName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">ANDERS THORESSON</consigneeName>
      <consigneeStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">TRKILSGATAN 13A</consigneeStreet>
      <consigneeCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GTEBORG</consigneeCity>
      <consigneePostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">416 78</consigneePostCode>
      <consigneeCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">SE</consigneeCountry>
      <aiStatementCode1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">BULKD</aiStatementCode1>
      <aiStatementText1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GEO/251LVBI/0916</aiStatementText1>
      <aiStatementCode2 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">LIC99</aiStatementCode2>
    </worksheetReportRow>
    <worksheetReportRow>
      <worksheetRefence xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">
        <worksheetReference xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetIdentityType">306</worksheetReference>
      </worksheetRefence>
      <invoiceNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">INTEBKKEN00000005672</invoiceNumber>
      <orderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">65406504</orderNumber>
      <incoTerm xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">CIF</incoTerm>
      <incoTermLocation xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">HEATHROW</incoTermLocation>
      <lineNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">5</lineNumber>
      <lineOrderNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">555</lineOrderNumber>
      <productCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">PROD05</productCode>
      <sku xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">SKU05</sku>
      <quantity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">1.000</quantity>
      <unitPrice xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">127.50</unitPrice>
      <itemNumber xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">0</itemNumber>
      <commodityCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">4901910000</commodityCode>
      <originCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">TH</originCountry>
      <goodsDescription xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">A SMALL TUB OF RAISINS</goodsDescription>
      <consignorName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">JASON HUEY</consignorName>
      <consignorStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">65 SIEGFREID RD</consignorStreet>
      <consignorCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">BERNVILLE</consignorCity>
      <consignorPostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">19506</consignorPostCode>
      <consignorCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">US</consignorCountry>
      <consigneeEori xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GBPR</consigneeEori>
      <consigneeName xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">ANDRE SANTOS</consigneeName>
      <consigneeStreet xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">AVENIDA PRAIA DA VITORIA</consigneeStreet>
      <consigneeCity xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">LISBOA</consigneeCity>
      <consigneePostCode xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">1000245</consigneePostCode>
      <consigneeCountry xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">PT</consigneeCountry>
      <aiStatementCode1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">BULKD</aiStatementCode1>
      <aiStatementText1 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">GEO/251LVBI/0916</aiStatementText1>
      <aiStatementCode2 xmlns="asm.org.uk/Sequoia/WorksheetReportData">LIC99</aiStatementCode2>
    </worksheetReportRow>
  </WorksheetReportRows>
</worksheetReport>
```

And my class is

```
namespace FreightSolutions
{
    public class GetWorksheetByRef : ISequoiaApiDualChannelServiceCallback
    {
        public void PublishMessage(PublishedMessage message)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(message.EventName);
        }

              public static TObject DeserializeFromXml<TObject>(string xml)
        {

            using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TObject));
                return ((TObject)(serializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
            }
        }

        //Main class method
        public void getWorksheetData(BuildWorksheetXML buildXml)
        {

            GetDeclarationResponseData apiCallBack = new GetDeclarationResponseData();
            SequoiaApiDualChannelServiceClient client = new SequoiaApiDualChannelServiceClient(new InstanceContext(apiCallBack));

            //Logon to Seqioia
            SequoiaLogonResponse loginResponse = client.Logon(new SequoiaLogonRequest { UserName = "api", Password = "api" });

            //Pass in reaquest Xml to local varialbe           
            string sendWorksheetInfo = buildXml.GenerateWorksheetXml;


            //Return response to local variale 
            SequoiaApiResponse returnWorksheetData = client.GetWorksheetReport(new ServiceReference1.LookUpRequest { Content = sendWorksheetInfo });

            if (returnWorksheetData != null)
            {

                //worksheetReport myWorksheetReportResponse = DeserializeFromXml<worksheetReport>(returnWorksheetData.ToString());

                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(worksheetReport));
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(returnWorksheetData.ReturnValue));

                worksheetReport myWorksheetReportResponse = (worksheetReport)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memStream);

                foreach (var worksheetReportitem in myWorksheetReportResponse.WorksheetReportRows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
@" WORKSHEEET RETURN DATA FOR REFERENCE: {0}
Trader Ref: {1}
",
               myWorksheetReportResponse.worksheetRefence,
               worksheetReportitem.traderReference   
                                   );

                    Console.ReadLine();

                }    }
        }
    }
}
```

The WorkSheetReportClass which was created automatically via XSD2Code is

```
namespace FreightSolutions {
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Xml.Schema;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    public partial class worksheetReport {

        private worksheetIdentityType worksheetRefenceField;

        private List<worksheetReportData> worksheetReportRowsField;

        public worksheetIdentityType worksheetRefence {
            get {
                return this.worksheetRefenceField;
            }
            set {
                this.worksheetRefenceField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=1)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("worksheetReportRow", IsNullable=false)]
        public List<worksheetReportData> WorksheetReportRows {
            get {
                return this.worksheetReportRowsField;
            }
            set {
                this.worksheetReportRowsField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When generating code from XSD2Code I had to set the GenerateOrderXMLProperties